# Angular2 Firebase Profile Route

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this following link:

```
 <p><a routerLink="/profile/{{(yourprofile$ | async)?.$value}}">Your Dashboard</a></p>
```

Which does not work. I get an error stating `Error: Cannot match any routes.`

How might I reformat my routerLink such that it winds up like `/profile/` + `{{(yourprofile$ | async)?.$value )}}`

The values come from my Firebase DB so as to fetch the username. However, I don't know that Firebase is exactly pertinent to this question.

Comment: Do you have a route with `path: '/profile/:id'` in your router configuraton?

Comment: I do. `{ path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileComponent }`